# Switch from fragment to activity in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

I made an application where I integrated the tabbed activity. In the tabbed activity I put 3 fragments. Now in the 3rd fragment I put a button and I want when I click on the button it redirects me to a new activity I did. I used an intent as we usually do between activities but it doesn't work. Need help please

Answer (score 0):

use `getContext` instade of `Activity.this`. use the below code in your button to redirect from fragment to activity

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Your_Activity.class));
        });
```

If the problem is not solved yet, let me know with `logcat` error.